# why does facebook's dialog.feed require an app_id

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, app-id, facebook-feed

I am using

`facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=...&caption=...&description=...`

Because it allows me to dynamically set the content of the share dialog box.

I do not understand why an `app_id` is required for this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Requiring an appid means the user had to give permission for your app to access their info... in theory anyway.  And for some reason some people are more interested in getting credit for their answers than in actually helping... its not like they get cash money for 'x' answers but thats how they are and you just have to accept that about them.

Comment: ppetree, thanks for responding.

it's odd that the regular sharer, facebookDOTcom/sharer.php?u=..., doesn't require an app_id. 

I wonder why fb differentiates between the sharer and facebookDOTcom/dialog/feed?app_id=...

Answer (score 3):

per the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ the app_id is used to identify your app so the following requirement can be confirmed by Facebook's backend systems. That requirement is "Note that the above example assumes that the user is already logged in and has authorized your application."

The old sharer.php is being deprecated.  I could only assume that it is due to abuse from people using it without having an app or a user's authorization.  Remember the days when we could trust our neighbors and leave our doors unlocked?  Those days are no more.

Comment: DMCS, thanks for your time...

But I'm still confused because: 
1) let's say I have mysite.com, 
2) I register it with fb and receive from them an app_id, 
3) later, John visits mysite and presses the share button, which actuates dialog.feed script.

In this scenario, John has NO relationship with mysite, other than merely visiting it, and pressing a button ... I do not understand what the app_id improves upon in this scenario.

It would, however, more easily enable fb to track things.

Comment: Did someone actually give me a -2 for asking this question?

Comment: The first rule of any education environment is that you don't punish someone for asking a question. User forums are very much education environments ... it is philosophically wrong to punish someone for asking a question ... if you don't like the question, then skip it ... I do this often in user forums when answering questions.

Comment: what! what kind of comment is that ... that's just rude ... it's like you are berating someone who is struggling with something ...  ... if you were struggling with something I would not be rude to you ... 

as far as ratings are concerned, give me a break ... I have been doing forums for 12 years, and a rating system is quite unnecessary.

Comment: and you did not answer my question ... I already knew the part that you told me ... that's not what my question was about ... hence my comment, 'but I'm still confused' ...

Comment: FWIW, I never down-voted your question. That was done by other users. I believe the requirement for App Id probably has something to do with all the abuse that sharer.php received from bad internet users. As you are probably aware with 12 years of forum experience, there's lots of people out there looking to cheat, abuse, or just disgrace something just for the hell of it, meaning people doing the right thing suffer and have new restrictions put on things, such as sharing something on FB via an open API. Hence why FBis trying to weed out some of the losers by forcing them to register an app.